# Is there a formula where you input an excel range and a column from said range can be outputted?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose there is a 2d array in excel. Is there a formula where you can isolate a column from that 2d array in Excel so that one could input it in another formula (for example)

Comment: index() and match(0 come to mind, but it's a wag based on the lack of info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Return Column From Array

For example, to get the 2nd column (`B1:B3`) from the range `A1:C3` you could use

```
=INDEX(A1:C3,0,2)
```

or (in Microsoft 365)

```
=CHOOSECOLS(A1:C3,2)
```

The latter additionally allows you to choose multiple columns e.g. to return an array of columns 1 and 3 (`A1:A3,C1:C3`) you could simply use

```
=CHOOSECOLS(A1:C3,1,3)
```